# can starting a battery dead car cause damage to anything?

Tags: starter, jump-start, damage

I just imported car from japan, I had to drive 1000km from shipping port to get it home.

Problem is Battery turned out to be plain dead. I stopped once at the fuel station and couldn't get it back online around halfway through my journay.

Being stranded, I tried multiple times. Waited few minutes and tried again.

I could hear starter click, but engine wouldn't come online.

My question is this, could I've caused permanent damage to my car trying to start it on low battery? I tried like 6 times before giving up and looking for jumpstart cables.

Comment: I'm guessing that it's an older car, 15+ or 25+ years old, the battery might be just plain dead. Buy a new battery or take it to a part store where they can test it. If the battery is good but drain, than you may have a charging issue. You'll have to check the charging circuit and  alternator. And no, you didn't do any damage, nothing was turning over.

Comment: @GabrielMongeon hey, it is 2009 vw golf. So not very old, its considered quasi new in my country :) shipping took 3 month in the container, this is the reason it died I guess.

Comment: Importing a VW golf from Japan? In which country do you live? Get your battery tested/checked/charged, I'm still suspecting a dead battery which is not uncommon for a 5 years old battery that have been sitting in a car for a long time. It's the cheapest thing to do.

Comment: @GabrielMongeon republic of georgia ^_^ vw from japan costs 3K$ less than in Europe for example. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything sensitive enough to be destroyed by an undervoltage condition will at least be protected by a relay, so it is highly unlikely you have damaged anything in the car.